# UITextFieldですべてのテキストを枠に表示させたい

Tags: ios, objective-c

UITextFieldのテキストを省略表示させずにフォントサイズを小さくして、すべてのテキストを枠の中に表示させようとしています。
　このとき、minimumFontSizeとadjustsFontSizeToFitWidthを設定し、xibでも同様の設定を行いましたが、画像のようにUITextFieldの文字のフォントが変わらず省略表示されてしまいます。下記に添付したコードは、すべてviewDidLoadに書かれており、その他のライフサイクルのメソッドにはコードを書いておりません。

UIButton,UILabelについてもadjustsFontSizeToFitWidthの設定を行い、比較すると、これら2つはフォントサイズが可変となり、枠内にすべて収まりました。
　
　環境はiOS9.2, Xcode7.2.1となります。

どなたか原因の分かる方いらっしゃいますでしょうか。

```
self.textField.minimumFontSize = 1.0f;
self.textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
[self.textField setText:@"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW"];
self.textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:241.0f/255.0f green:247.0f/255.0f blue:210.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

[image: UITextFieldとUIButton、UILabelの比較]

[image: xib上での設定]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下の質問は同様の現象ではないでしょうか。
このページでの解決方法は、テキストをセットした、もしくはテキストが変化した時に適切なフォントを計算してフォントをセットし直しているようです。
[iphone - Can't get UITextField to autoshrink text - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350045/cant-get-uitextfield-to-autoshrink-text#comment35588809_16356147)